# Pass the size of a data set to an angular service

Tags: angularjs

Pass the size of the data set to angular service. I am trying to pass the size of the data set(count) to the angular service. I just started to work with angular and any help is greatly appreciated.

Controler:

```
public JsonResult GetAllCurrentSettings()
    {
        var jsonString = string.Empty;

        string query = "SELECT  * from test";

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStringApps))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dt.Load(rdr);
                    }

                    jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.None);
                    return Json(jsonString);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            return Json(jsonString);
        }
    }
```

Angular Service

```
myApp.service('allCurrentSettingsService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
        var allSettings = null;
        this.getList = function () {
            var def = $q.defer()
            if (allSettings) {
                def.resolve(allSettings);
            } else {
                $http.post('GetAllCurrentSettings')
                  .then(function (response) {
                      var response = $.parseJSON(response.data)
                      allSettings = response;
                      def.resolve(allSettings);
                  });
            }
            return def.promise;
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$http.post('GetAllCurrentSettings')
              .then(function (response) {
                  var response = $.parseJSON(response.data)
```

The response is already a JSON object.

> $.parseJSON : Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript value.

You can directly use response object like this:

```
def.resolve(response);
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I pass the count from the service?

Comment: return Json(<any kind of object>). This helper method converts object to JSON for you. Just use as: return Json(count)